# OpenWRT Buildroot add package

Tags: openssl, wifi, openwrt

I have an aim to compile my software for my target system, running under OpenWRT. I've built toolchain and all other system, for no reason. But it doesn't matter. Now I've recognized that I missed one dependency for my software (openssl). How can I make it available to the toolchain? I've run feed install and make package/openssl/install. But include/openssl/ didn't appeare in standing_dir.

Comment: Have you tried to build openssh? It has openssl as dependency. So if the build will be successful, you'll have all necessary libraries/headers in your staging directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm blind. There are one line in OpenWRT documentation, says that all built packages' files dispoce at staging_dir/target-*/ directory.